# I am trying to add the Euro values like 1.000,00 using input tag In Laravel 5.4

Tags: html, input, laravel-5

I have problem with enter euro currency type inputs( example: 1.000,00 ).how can l enter this kind of values using input tags?

**Blade**

```
<div class="md-form">
      <input type="text" step="0.01" id="price" name="price" class="form-control">
      <label for="price" class="">Product price &euro;</label>
</div>
```

This is the Error message after input values like 1.000,00

[image]

This is Product table structure[image]

please help me to find the solution.Thank you

Comment: can you share your products database design ? by typing `describe products` in mysql

Comment: ok.i added.thank you. @Rodrane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store your currency using a decimal, as Mr Lister has said.

You then use the [`money_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) method to display the currency in your preferred format.

```
$number = 1234.56;

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'de_DE');
echo money_format('%.2n', $number) . "\n";
// Eu 1.234,56
```

I know that Laravel has locale support for languages, etc, but I've not seen anything for currencies.

I would therefore add the appropriate `setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'de_DE');` call to the `boot` method of the `AppServiceProvider`. This can be found in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php`.

I would suggest adding an attribute accessor to your `Product` model.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var array  Accessors to append to the model's array form.
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'price_formatted',
    ];

    // ...

    /**
     * Get formatted product price.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPriceFormattedAttribute()
    {
        return money_format('%.2n', $this->price);
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can then access the value using:

```
$product->price // 1234.56
$product->price_formatted // Eu 1.234,56
```

Comment: where should i add this?

Comment: @RuwanthaSameera - I've added some more detail to my answer. Hopefully this points you in a helpful direction.

Comment: @fubar-Thank you very much for your guidence. Its very usefull.

Answer (score 1):

`100.000,00` is not a proper double value you cannot use **comma** on double values. You will get same error in **discount** too. Your price and discount fields should be `100.000` and `1.000` without any comma seperated parts. You can check my test below.

As @mr.lister mentioned in comments you should never store this kind of value as double. For higher precision go for `Decimal`

P.S: I used quotes in last 2 because then I will recieve column count error. You can use quotes in first one too.

[image]

Comment: Also, you should never use `double` type fields to store currency values.

Comment: it is his design not mine :p you better tell him ^^

Comment: @Rodrane Yes. That's why i ask this question. I want add 1.000,00 type values.  Some countries using this way to show currency. Norway and spanish and etc. [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html)

Comment: @MrLister thank you for your guidence. I'll correct it

Comment: if I were you I would keep this kind of information as a decimal instead of double

Comment: @Rodrane i used decimal before but when i try to add that kind of inputs it  show errors.